# Validate, prefill and potentially block while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a field where user has to fill in their social security number.

If the users birthdate is the 14th of November 1990

The social security starts with 90.11.14-XXX.XX (X represents random number 0-9)

I'm using simple_form

```
<%= f.input :ssn, 
            label: t('employee.social_security_no'),
            input_html: { placeholder: "XX.XX.XX - XXX.XX" }%>
```

I would like to achieve the following:

1) How can I preset the input field set with 90.11.27-_ _ _ . _ _

2) and validate that the remaining 5 numbers are actually numbers

3)  and limit the field so that user cannot fill in more than 5 extra digits.

Any help to get me on the way is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really want to achieve, but you can do as follows:

1) Preset with 'value' option like below.(But users should delete '_' characters by themselves)

```
<%= f.input :ssn,
  label: t('employee.social_security_no'),
  input_html: { value: "#{@user.birthdate.strftime('%y.%m.%d')}-___.__" },
  maxlength: 15
%>
```

2) Check the number format with regular expression in server side, so add these line in the model. (This validates whole the ssn format with XX.XX.XX-XXX.XX)

```
ssn_regexp = /\A\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}-\d{3}\.\d{2}\z/

validates :ssn,
  format: { with: ssn_regexp }
```

3) 'maxlength' option limits the length of numbers to be filled in the input field.